# App not approved, only want to get posts from public page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently in the process of retrieving posts from a public Facebook page. I created an app and executed following command:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%my_clientid%&client_secret=%my_secret%&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

The above returns an access token. However, after running our script to get the posts, an error occurs telling me:

> Facebook\FacebookPermissionException: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review. in /var/www/sources/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 128

Clear message, so I described my app and submit for review. After a couple of days Facebook declined and wrote the following:

> We couldn't find the Facebook Login button in your app.
>   Please make sure that the button is easy to find and consistent

and

> Page public content access is meant only for aggregated, anonymized public content that is meant to be used as comparative analytics.

I don't understand what's the problem? I just want to retrieve the public posts from a public page and show the post on our website. The user should not need to authorize, so why would I place a login button?

It worked before, did the policy changed and we are no longer able to gather public posts?

Comment: Seems to me you have fallen foul of the new look _Facebook are the good guys_ changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS lists this as one common usage, _“Provide aggregated, anonymized public content to allow people to follow and track stories that are relevant to them”_ - but if I don’t even log in to your page, then how would you know what is relevant to me? If you pick what pages to show content from for me - then you might as well just link me to their Facebook URL directly, no?

Comment: @CBroe Our website has a masonry of items, these items resemble Facebook posts from their Facebook page. Basically, I want to retrieve the title and the url to the Facebook post from the page and show it on our website.

Comment: @Lars Did you succeed your app review? We are facing the same issue, the permissions that we need have been approved but the app verification failed with the exact same message "We couldn't find the Facebook Login button in your app." Also, there is no room to add comments for this specific element "App review". Thanks!

Comment: @SebastienDErrico I have not succeeded yet in confirming the review. The fact I cannot reply to the review report is indeed a big issue, s I do not know where to go from here. There is also the chance I created the wrong Facebook app and should be doing something different.